# emacs icicles delete selection mode

Tags: emacs, icicles

When I turn on icicles mode in emacs, it kinda mess up delete-selection-mode. 
After copied some text, if I try to yank it into a highlighted region, instead of replace that region, it will append at the end of the region. I say kinda because, I could still use backspace or directly type text to replace the highlighted region. Only yanking behavior is not right.

Is there some option in icicles mode to fix this yank behavior? So far I haven't found any.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like something that should be reported to the maintainer of icicles mode.

Answer (score 1):

M-x icicle-send-bug-report RET

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `M-x icicle-send-bug-report RET`

Give a complete recipe, starting from `emacs -Q`.  It sounds like you have some other setting somewhere that is interfering.  I use **Icicles** with `delete-selection-mode` all the time.